# Open mail app on firmware 3.1

Tags: iphone

I would like to make an app to open the native app mail on my iPhone. The problem is that I'm able to do it but the mail app opens on compose a new blank Message, and not on the Main view.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to open other apps from an iPhone application.

You can only open the Mail app via a mailto URL, and that -as you said- will give you the compose view.